# Reverse sql that undo a query

Tags: postgresql, django-migrations

query:

```
UPDATE "table_name"
SET properties = properties || jsonb_build_object('$ip', ip)
WHERE ip IS NOT NULL;
```

I am running a Django migration, I need the reverse sql that undo the results of executing this query and restores the table in the previous state.

Because when I run the django migration test for the following operation:

```
operations = [
        # migrations.RunPython(migrate_event_ip_to_property, rollback),
        migrations.RunSQL(
            """
            UPDATE "table_name"
            SET properties = properties || jsonb_build_object('$ip', ip)
            WHERE ip IS NOT NULL;
            """,
            None
        )
    ]
```

I get IrreversibleError. I think if I provide the reverse sql, instead of None, it might work

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck looking for a raw solution from postgresql as SQL transaction was already commited by Django migration. See [Postgresql ROLLBACK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-rollback.html)

But in this case you can revert to last working migration using:

`./manage.py migrate app XXXX_last_working_migration`

As stated in Django's django-admin docs migrate section [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/)